# Minimal Polynomial Product

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Given $u,v\in V$, $dim V=n$, $f:V\to V$ is linear operator. If $m_u(x), m_v(x)$ are minimal polynomials with $mdc(m_u(x),m_v(x))=1$ then the minimal polynomial of $u+v$, $m_{u+v}$, is $m_u(x).m_v(x)$.

I am trying to open the definition but i don't see how i can prove that is minimal. Some hint?

Comment: Consider $u=0, v=I$. Then $m_u(x) = x$, $m_v(x) = x-1$ and they have $\gcd = 1$ but $m_{u+v}(x)$ is not $x(x-1)$.